# Lan (wired) connection not working anymore

Tags: networking, network-manager, lan

I have been using Ubuntu for the last few years and always found a solution on my own. Now I have a question for which I need your help:
Last week, my lan connection suddenly stopped working. No updates, no changes at the router. I use Ubuntu 16.04.
The issue is not with the cable, any other device connects perfectly with same cable. WiFi is working perfectly fine.

Any ideas? I will list output of "ifconfig":

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 28:d2:44:20:50:f8  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
      Interrupt:20 Memory:f3900000-f3920000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:639 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:639 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
      RX bytes:53809 (53.8 KB)  TX bytes:53809 (53.8 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 3c:a9:f4:56:79:54  
      inet addr:192.168.0.192  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::3ea9:f4ff:fe56:7954/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:4658 errors:0 dropped:600 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:3619 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:3552416 (3.5 MB)  TX bytes:478082 (478.0 KB)
```

Output of "sudo lshw -class network"

```
*-network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 19
   bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 04
   serial: 28:d2:44:20:50:f8
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.13-3 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
   resources: irq:27 memory:f3900000-f391ffff memory:f393b000-f393bfff ioport:6080(size=32)
*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Centrino Ultimate-N 6300
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 3e
   serial: 3c:a9:f4:56:79:54
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-66-generic firmware=9.221.4.1 build 25532 ip=192.168.0.192 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
   resources: irq:31 memory:f3000000-f3001fff
```

**Note: Ethernet interface: link=no**

Any help is appreciated. Will post other outputs if something else is required.

Comment: please [edit] your question and add the output of ` sudo lshw -C network`

Comment: what happened when you do `sudo ifconfig eth0 down` and `sudo ifconfig eth0 up` ?

Comment: Nothing.  No error message though. But still no connection.

Comment: what happened when you do `sudo dhclient eth0` ?

Comment: I wonder if you have any HW problem - do you have any LEDs on the ethernet-card which blinks/doesn't blink?

Comment: with `sudo dhclient eth0` there is no reply in terminal. It just goes on in a "loop" for minutes. HW problem might be true, for there is no blinking at all.

Comment: seems like an HW issue, do you have another cable to try with this network-card (I understood that the cable/router seems to be fine..). do you have an usb-ethernet device which you can try to use with your ubuntu instead of your network-card?

Comment: Other cables don't work either, so it probably really is the card. which isn't recognized. No, have no usb ethernet device.

Answer (score 0):

As described in the question and comments:

- `eth0` network link status is `link=no`
- Other devices using the same cable/router can connect to the Internet

  - The problem is not with the cable/router
- The computer worked with the same software/cable/router until a few days ago, and since then it doesn't work anymore
- the network-card LEDs doesn't blink

**Conclusion**

- It seems like hardware problem with the network-card.

**Suggested solutions:**

- Use Wifi only
- buy USB->ethernet dongle and use Ethernet over USB
- Fix/replace the network-card

Comment: Thanks! Will have a look at the card and try to fix/replace it. Will uptdate/edit as soon as I have dealt with it during the week.